# Javascript--Breeze Manager Not Detecting Changes

Tags: javascript, c#, breeze, entitymanager

I'm using the EntityManager from Breeze for the API portion of data-binding.  However, the EntityManager fails to track the changes. It will execute the code like it's supposed to but it never recognizes the changes. What's the issue? Please, refrain from saying anything that is not constructive or any personal attacks. We're here as professionals and scientists(i know i am).  Here is my code:

Service:

```
(function () {
var serviceId = 'UWRLService';
angular.module('myApp')
    .factory(serviceId, ['$q', 'breeze', 'logger', 'appSettings', UWRLService]);
// console.log('Initialized UWRL Service.js');
function UWRLService($q, breeze, logger, appSettings) {
   // console.log('inside datacontext -- UWRLService');
    // configure logging for this service
    logger = logger.forSource(serviceId);
    var logError = logger.logError;
    var logSuccess = logger.logSuccess;
    var logWarning = logger.logWarning;
    //Setup variables with common Breeze query classes
    var entityQuery = breeze.EntityQuery;

    // setup breeze entity manager       
    var serviceName = appSettings.apiUrl + '/breeze/Uwrl/';//Where the entire service is pointing to

    var manager = new breeze.EntityManager(serviceName);
    var entityStateChangeAction = breeze.EntityAction.EntityStateChange;


    // expose methods 
    var service = {
        getChangesCount: getChangesCount,
        saveChanges: saveChanges, 
        rejectChanges: rejectChanges,
        getDivisions: getDivisions,
        getPools: getPools,
        getRandomCust: getRandomCust
        //createChangeFactorEntity: createChangeFactorEntity,
    };
    return service;

    //           FUNCTION DECLARATIONS
    //Attaches a new entity to the Breeze repository 
    //Passes the name and an array of values to seed the entity with
    //function createChangeFactorEntity(entityName, initialValues) {
    //    var newFactor = manager.createEntity(entityName, initialValues);
    //    return newFactor;
    //}

    function getRandomCust()
    {
        var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from('alpha')
                        .where('customerNumber', '==', 1);
        return executeQuery(query, 'Alpha found!');
    }

    function getDivisions()
    {
        var query = breeze.EntityQuery
            .from('Divisions');

            //executeQuery([query name], [query title])
        return executeQuery(query, 'Divisions Found');
    }

    function getPools()
    {
        var query = breeze.EntityQuery
                    .from('Pools');
        return executeQuery(query, 'Pools Found');
    }

    //Saves changes and logs exceptions
    function saveChanges() {
        var hasChanges = manager.hasChanges();
        console.log(hasChanges);
        console.log(manager.getChanges());

        return manager.saveChanges()
            .then(saveSucceeded)
            .catch(saveFailed);

        function saveSucceeded(saveResult) {
            logSuccess("# of items saved = " + saveResult.entities.length, null, true);
            logger.log(saveResult);
        }

        function saveFailed(error) {
            var reason = error.message;
            var detail = error.detail;

            if (error.entityErrors) {
                //Do nothing
            } else if (detail && detail.ExceptionType &&
                detail.ExceptionType.indexOf('OptimisticConcurrencyException') !== -1) {
                // Concurrency error 
                reason =
                    "Another user, perhaps the server, " +
                    "may have deleted one or all of the todos." +
                    " You may have to restart the app.";
            } else {
                reason = "Failed to save changes: " + reason +
                    " You may have to restart the app.";
            }

            logError(reason, error, true);

            throw error; //Downstream: users know it has failed
        }
    }

    //Discards changes in Breeze Manager
    function rejectChanges() {
        if (manager.hasChanges()) {
            count = getChangesCount();
            manager.rejectChanges();
            logWarning('Discarded ' + count + ' pending changes(s)', null, true);
        }
    }

    //Returns (Nth-1) index of Breeze manager getChanges array
    function getChangesCount() {
        var ents = manager.getEntities();
        var changes = manager.getChanges();
        if (changes.length > 0)
        {
            alert("Changes made: " + manager.getChanges().length);
        }
        return manager.getChanges().length;
    }

    //Query Execution w/ toasters(logger)
    function executeQuery(query, entityType) {

        var promise = manager.executeQuery(query).then(querySucceeded, queryFailed);
        return promise;

        function querySucceeded(response) {
            logSuccess(entityType + " query was successful", null, true);

            return response.results;
        }

        function queryFailed(response) {
            var message = response.message || entityType + " query failed";
            logError(message, response, true);
            throw error;
        }
    }
};
})()
```

Controller (javascript):

```
(function () {
'use strict';
var controllerId = 'UWRLController';
// console.log('Initialized UWRLController');
//Last item in passed array is the Controller (specific)
angular.module('myApp').controller(controllerId, 
['$scope', 'UWRLService', 'logger',                                                                             
'$routeParams', 'allStatesService', UWRLController]);

function UWRLController($scope, UWRLService, logger, $routeParams, allStatesService) {
   // console.log('inside UWRLController');
    //Loggin Initialization       
    logger = logger.forSource(controllerId);
    var logError = logger.logError;
    var logSuccess = logger.logSuccess;
    var logWarning = logger.logWarning;

    var uwrl = {};
    $scope.uwrl = uwrl;
    //Parameters we pass from Renewal Group Maintenance screen
    //uwrl.PlanCode = $routeParams.PlanCode;
    //uwrl.Contract = $routeParams.ContractNumber;
    //uwrl.Mch = $routeParams.Mch;

    //Functions in Javascript Controller
    //[scope].[property] = [function name]
    uwrl.saveChanges = save;
    uwrl.discardChanges = discardChanges;
    uwrl.changesCount = changesCount();
    //uwrl.select = select;
    init();//Initialize all customer related data for page

    function init()
    {
        gettingDivisions();//Initialze getting data from Division's table through UWRL-service.js
        getAllFiftyStates();
        gettingPools();
        gettingRandom();
    }

    function gettingRandom()
    {
        UWRLService.getRandomCust()
                .then(function(alpha)
                {
                    uwrl.alpha = alpha;
                    uwrl.beta = uwrl.alpha[0].customerName;
                });
    }

    function gettingDivisions()
    {
        UWRLService.getDivisions()
            .then(function (divisionNumber) {
                uwrl.divisionNumber = divisionNumber;
            });
    }

    function getAllFiftyStates()
    {
        allStatesService.getStates()
            .then(function (allStates)
            {
                uwrl.allStates = allStates;
            });
    }

    function gettingPools()
    {          
        UWRLService.getPools()
            .then(function (poolNumber)
            {
                uwrl.poolNumber = poolNumber;
            });
    }

    //Clicking the Drop-down Button
    //function select(change) {
    //    this.MchMcpPlanDesignId = change.MchMcpPlanDesign.MchMcpPlanDesignId;
    //    change.expanded = !change.expanded; //toggle back and forth           
    //}


    ////.then = [if] success
    ////.fail = failure
    ////.finally = always executed despite evaluated conditionals        
    //function getPlans() {//returns a promise
    //    uwrl.loadingPlans = true;
    //    UWRLService.getChangeFactors(uwrl.Mch, uwrl.Contract, uwrl.PlanCode)
    //        .then(function (deltaChangeFactor) {
    //            uwrl.deltaChangeFactor = deltaChangeFactor;
    //        }).finally(function () { uwrl.loadingPlans = false; });
    //}

    ////Returns all data in ChangeFactorType table
    //function getChangeFactorTypes() {
    //    UWRLService.getTypes().then(function (changeFactorTypes) {
    //        uwrl.changeFactorTypes = changeFactorTypes;
    //    });
    //}

    //Clicking on Save Button
    function save() {
        console.log('Save Button Clicked!');
        //Validation -- checks for empty values
        //if (uwrl.changeFactorType != null && uwrl.effectiveDate != null &&
        //   uwrl.changeFactorAmount != null) {
        //    //Adds a new Breeze Entity for ChangeFactor table in SQL database
        //    UWRLService.createChangeFactorEntity('ChangeFactor',
        //    {
        //        MchMcpPlanDesignId: this.MchMcpPlanDesignId,
        //        ChangeFactorType: uwrl.changeFactorType,
        //        EffectiveDate: uwrl.effectiveDate,
        //        ChangeFactorAmount: uwrl.changeFactorAmount
        //    });
        //}
        //Saves to Breeze Manager
        //Must hit Art's ESB service -- to be researched
        UWRLService.saveChanges();
    }

    //Gets rid of changes and logs it
    function discardChanges() {
       console.log('Discard Button Clicked!');
        UWRLService.rejectChanges();
    }

    //Notifies user(s) of changes made that are
    //either: savable, discardable 
    function changesCount() {
       // console.log("Changes Made: " + UWRLService.getChangesCount)//for debugging purposes
        return UWRLService.getChangesCount;
    }
};
})();
```

Comment: Where is the code that makes the changes that are not detected?

Comment: function changesCount in the controller and UWRLSErvice.getChangesCount in that function and getChangesCount in the service (UWRLService).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to make sure to effect the model. For example: uwrl.alpha[0].customerName instead of urwl.beta